# How to run sentry on premise version on docker swarm

Tags: docker-compose, devops, docker-swarm, sentry, docker-swarm-mode

I'm new to sentry, We have a running sentry version 9.1.2 and I wanted to uprade to the latest one, How should I deploy it in docker swarm mode, as the repo of sentry [self-hosted](https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted#readme) has no docs to deploy it on swarm network, and there are bunch of scripts to run before deployment, can you guys help me in deploying it in a more simpler way ? Or there are also one image of getsentry/sentry but there are no docs for it.

I wanted to deploy sentry: latest version into docker swarm network